# Cycle length in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Can someone check my proof? I never used the assumption that $G$ is connected, so I am a little worried about it.

Theorem. Let $G$ be a connected graph with at least one cycle.  Then $G$ has at least one cycle with length $\leq 2 \text{ diam} (G)+1$.

proof. Take a cycle $C=x_1,...,x_n$ in $G$ of minimal length $n$. Suppose $n\geq 2 \text{ diam} (G)+2$.

Consider two paths in $C$:

$$P=x_1,...,x_{\text{diam}(G)+2}, \text{ and}$$
$$Q=x_{\text{diam}(G)+2},...,x_n,x_1.$$

Each has length $\geq \text{ diam} (G)+1$. There is a path $P'$ in $G$ from $x_1$ to $x_{\text{diam}(G)+2}$ with length $\leq \text{diam} (G)$. Since $P'\neq Q$, $P'$ must leave $Q$ and re-enter $Q$, creating shorter cycle. Contradiction.

Comment: It appears that the connectedness condition is only to ensure that the diameter is finite; your argument implicitly makes that assumption.

Comment: If $G$ is not connected, then $diam(G)=\infty$. So, the condition always holds.

Comment: @Peter Ok, so if you define diameter like that (which is how I would do it), then the theorem holds without assuming $G$ is connected.  In my book I think distance (diameter too) is only defined in connected graphs, so I guess that is why "connected" needs to be included.

Comment: This would be plausible.

Comment: Your theorem translates to proposition 1.3.2 on page 9 of Diestel's "Graph Theory", 4th edition, ISBN-10: 3642142788.